# Convert the integral from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates and solve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Convert the integral from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates and solve

I think I know how to do this, but I just want to double check my method.  So assuming I have the below problem:

$$\int^2_0\int^\sqrt{2x-x^2}_0xy dy dx$$

Since:

$$x=rcos\theta$$

$$y=rsin\theta$$

Is it then true that the integral becomes:

$$\int^2_0\int^\sqrt{2rcos\theta-r^2cos^2\theta}_0rcos\theta\; rsin\theta\; r\;dr\; d\theta$$

$$\int^2_0\int^\sqrt{2rcos\theta-r^2cos^2\theta}_0r^3cos\theta\; sin\theta\; dr\; d\theta$$

$$\int^2_0 \frac{r^4}{4}cos\theta\; sin\theta\; |^{\sqrt{2rcos\theta-r^2cos^2\theta}}_0\;d\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\int^{2}_{0}(r\;cos\theta\; (2-r\;cos\theta))^4cos\theta\; sin\theta\; d\theta$$

Is this correct thus far?

**EDIT**

Attempting to convert to cylindrical coordinates again:

$$y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$$

$$r\;sin\theta\;=\sqrt{2r\;cos\theta-r^2cos^2\theta}$$

$$r^2\;sin^2\theta=2r\;cos\theta-r^2cos^2\theta$$

$$r^2sin^2\theta-2r\;cos\theta+r^2cos^2\theta=0$$

$$r^2(sin^2\theta+cos^2\theta)=2r\;cos\theta$$

$$r=2cos\theta$$

$$\int^2_0\int^{2cos\theta}_0r^3\;cos\theta\;sin\theta\;dr\;d\theta$$

Comment: $(1)$ Just look at your formula after the polar transformation.  That couldn't possibly be right, could it?  Afterall, after you take the integral wrt $r$ *you'll still have $r$'s left*.  $(2)$ Does the question ask you to use cylindrical coordinates? This works out pretty simply in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Either way, when doing a coordinate transformation you don't just blindly plug in expressions in the bounds of integration.  You draw the region and parametrize it in the new coordinates.

Comment: @gotit--thanks thanks for the comments!  I wouldn't say I was doing it 'blindly' but these are the conversions I was given for cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @gotit--thanks hello, I tried following your suggestions and reworking this problem.  Can you tell me if I now have the integral setup properly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first limits are correct, but not the second, the angle would be only between 0 and pi/2 based on the area if you draw on a graph.

Comment: How were you able to determine the angle being between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @inquisitor You just have to plot/ tabulate some values of $r=2\cos(\theta)$ at a few values of $\theta$ and [determine where it should start and end](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3D2cos%28theta%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2) based on the plot/ table you make.